# Отображение svg на iPhone

Tags: html, css, svg, iphone

На iPhone слайдер отображается не корректно, на всех остальных платформах такой проблемы нет. Пробовал заходить с разных браузеров и чистить кеш, но проблема остается. Изображения вставляются через тег svg. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема или посоветуйте нормальный эмулятор iOS с поддержкой веб-инспектора.

[Ссылка на слайдер](https://www.spasibo.life/?Order_ID=1581330078#modal2)

Скрин с айфона:
[image: Скрин с айфона:]

Скрин с андроида:
[image: Скрин с андроида]

Comment: код тоже необходимо приложить к вопросу :)

Comment: @Владислав Черемнов Если у вас внутри SVG используется `href="#..."`  попробуйте заменить на `xlink:href="#.."` так как IOS не воспринимает `href`

Comment: У меня на андроиде вообще нету этой завитушки